# How can I get zipfile to instantiate with a UI wrapper

Tags: python

I have been trying to use the class library *appJar* which is a nice basic UI for Python. I Have working code that performs the functions that I require, however, when I wrap the UI around it, it does not run, and UI's have far less feedback on break points

The relevant code is here:

```
def zipdir(path, ziph):
# ziph is zipfile handle
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fromDirectory):
    for file in files:
        with Archive.progressbar.progressbar(max_value=10) as progress:
            for i in range(1):
                filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                ziph.write(filePath, relpath(filePath, ""))
                time.sleep(0.1)
                progress.update(i)
def beginBackup(btn):
    return app.questionBox("Ready?", "Click OK ")
```

The above setups up the functions, and the below should run it but it doesn't

```
try:
    if (beginBackup == True):
        print(beginBackup)
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
        zipf.close()
        os.rename('Python.zip', "bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")
        shutil.move("bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip", str(toDirectory) + "/bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")
else:
    raise Exception("Something went wrong")
except Exception as e:
    app.warningBox("Error", "Something went wrong: {}".format(str(e)))
```

I feel like it is because I am placing the code in the wrong place, since it feels like it never instantiates the backup process.

Here is the full code:

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil
import time
from os.path import relpath
from appJar import gui

# Global Variables
fromDirectory = ""
toDirectory = ""
fileName = time.time()
fileVersion = 1.2

# Setting up the mechanism
def backupsource(btn):
    fromDirectory = app.directoryBox(title="Source")

def backupdest(btn):
    toDirectory = app.directoryBox(title="Destination")

def zipdir(path, ziph):
    # ziph is zipfile handle
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(fromDirectory):
        for file in files:
            with Archive.progressbar.progressbar(max_value=10) as progress:
                for i in range(1):
                    filePath = os.path.join(root, file)
                    ziph.write(filePath, relpath(filePath, ""))
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    progress.update(i)
def beginBackup(btn):
    return app.questionBox("Ready?", "Click OK ")

# Open the GUI
app = gui()
app.showSplash("Simple zip v. 1.2", fill="grey", stripe="#ADDFAD", fg="white", font=44)

# Setup the visual styles of the app
app.setTitle("Simple Zip")
app.setIcon("img/logo.ico")
app.setGeometry(400, 300)
app.setResizable(canResize=True)

# Items inside of the GUI
app.addLabel("title", "Welcome to the simple backup utility")
app.setLabelBg("title", "gray")
app.addLabel("Backup", "Label goes here")

# Setup source buttons
app.addButton("Source", backupsource)
app.addButton("Destination", backupdest)

# Begin Backup section
app.addButton("Backup!", beginBackup)

# start the GUI
app.go()

try:
    if (beginBackup == True):
        print(beginBackup)
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
        zipf.close()
        os.rename('Python.zip', "bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")
        shutil.move("bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip", str(toDirectory) + "/bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")
else:
    raise Exception("Something went wrong")   

 except Exception as e:
        app.warningBox("Error", "Something went wrong: {}".format(str(e)))
```

Comment: `os.renames` => `os.rename`. And why renaming + moving when you could do all with `shutil.move` ?

Comment: I made the adjustment to the `os.rename`, I probably could do it all with the `shutil.move`, it was an old holdover from when I was writing it as a console app. The idea was to create the file, _then_ move it using shutil which is probably redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First error I'm spotting is `os.renames`, which doesn't exist. But I cannot advise to find errors blinldy like this. I'd rewrite that with exception wrapper (and short-circuit that useless `rename` command since `shutil.move` can handle renaming+moving across filesystems.

Then you do `app.go()` but nothing passes this line. It's the GUI mainloop. From now, `appJar` dispatches the events. You have no control about main routine anymore.

So everything must be done here (code activated when you press the button):

```
def beginBackup(btn):
    return app.questionBox("Ready?", "Click OK ")
```

that pops up a window and does nothing more. It should be replaced by the full code:

```
def beginBackup(btn):
    if not app.questionBox("Ready?", "Click OK"):
      app.warningBox("Error", "Cancelled")
    else:
      try:
        zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        zipdir('tmp/', zipf)
        zipf.close()
        shutil.move('Python.zip', str(toDirectory) + "/bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")
      except Exception as e:
        app.warningBox("Error", "Something went wrong: {}".format(str(e)))
```

so now if anything happens in that callback, you get a nice warning box telling you exactly what it is (cannot open file, syntax error, etc ...)

Comment: I have not tested with a try/except wrapper, but I was having issues getting anything to print to the console at all. I will test and comment back

Comment: I edited the code as you mentioned here (and updated the post above) there is literally nothing being posted to the console. I am still new at this so debugging or putting in verbose code to feed to the console is still new to me

Comment: I missed the point before. There were several mistakes, but a very big conceptual one. You should read about GUI systems. In the meanwhile, my answer should do the trick.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Yes I am still very new at this, so your recommendation helped a lot, now I can see where it is choking, though I am not sure how to fix it now. It looks almost like it is hanging, or I am not giving it enough time to finish. Might need to add a status bar to monitor the progress? I am not sure

Comment: Per your instructions everything works save for this line:
`shutil.move('Python.zip', str(toDirectory) + "/bak" + str(fileName) + ".zip")` which moves the file (I am not sure where to), but not to the target `toDirectory`